# URL in sitemap with 404 error. Strange parameter at the end of the URL

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, sitemap, 404, yoast

in my sitemap generated with SEO Yoast, there are some URL in 404 error.

In the image you can see a strange parameter at the end of the URL.

The sitemap is "attachment-sitemap1.xml", so there are images that doesn't exist.

How i can resolve this? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Those could be session ids.  Do you have a WordPress plugin that can track sessions without cookies?

Comment: thank you for the answer. I don't think, my plugins are:

Admin Word Count Column,
Anti-spam,
Column Shortcodes,
EWWW Image Optimizer,
Genesis Translations,
Login LockDown,
Nofollow for external link,
Q2W3 Fixed Widget,
Quick Adsense,
Redirection,
Subscribe to Comments Reloaded,
W3 Total Cache,
WP MoneyClick,
Yoast SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this (assuming you use Wordpress for all website management) is to disable all of the plugins at the start then for each full website test, enable one plugin at a time and attempt to generate the sitemap files in each test.

The moment you see that unexplained extensions are added to your URLs in the sitemap files is an indicator that the last plugin you enabled is the one that needs to be reconfigured or removed.

Comment: i think it's a Yoast problem. In the section "Media & attachment URLs"

"Redirect attachment URLs to the attachment itself?"

It was on No. Now i click on Yes, resend the sitemap and the problem seems to have disappeared. So the problem was the last update of Yoast:

https://kb.yoast.com/kb/images-in-the-xml-sitemap/

What do you think about? :)

Comment: I'm not sure why I scored -1 for my answer if the OP confirmed the problem was with a version of a wordpress plugin he/she was using?

Comment: i haven't scored -1, i select your as the best answer.